# Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender) removed in Test cases

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I am migrating all old legacy **Log4j1.x Test cases to Log4j2.x** based test cases, I've a test case like below, which I am not able to convert, condition is I dont want to change anything in asserts.

**Note: I can't use Junit 5, because its legacy code, is there any way we can still use log4j 2.x with the Junit 4 and try to fix the original issues?**

Need solution.

```
@Mock 
AppenderSkeleton appender;
@Captor 
ArgumentCaptor<LoggingEvent> logCaptor;

@Test
public void testHeaderFooterValidationWithHeaderFooterInfoDisabled() {
    Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender);
    
    
    //Turn off header and footer read
    testLoader.setEnableHeaderInfo(false);
    testLoader.setEnableTrailerInfo(false);
    
    //Turn on header footer validation
    testLoader.setValidateHeader(true);
    verify(appender, times(1)).doAppend(logCaptor.capture());
    assertEquals("Warning message should have been logged", "Some Message", logCaptor.getValue().getRenderedMessage());
    
    testLoader.setValidateTrailer(true);
    verify(appender, times(2)).doAppend(logCaptor.capture());
    assertEquals("Warning message should have been logged", "Some Message", logCaptor.getValue().getRenderedMessage());
    
    testLoader.processEvent(paramsMap);
    
    assertThat(configRegion.values()).contains("AAAA,BBBB,CCCC");
    assertThat(configRegion.keySet()).contains("abc.config.property");
}
```

I tried to replace

```
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender);
```

To

```
ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLogger  = builder.newRootLogger(Level.ERROR);
rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("stdout"));
builder.add(rootLogger);
```

Comment: Did you check the related question links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713891/appenderskeleton-log4j2 ? Do you need to move all output to console?

Answer (score 1):

In Log4j2 you have a [`ListAppender`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-core/src/test/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/test/appender/ListAppender.java) in the `tests` JAR.

Combined with the [`LoggerContextSource`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-core/src/test/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/junit/LoggerContextSource.java) JUnit 5 extension it allows you to inject a `ListAppender` in your test. E.g.:

```java
@Test
@LoggerContextSource("log4j2-test.xml")
public void testHeaderFooterValidationWithHeaderFooterInfoDisabled(@Named("List") Appender appender) {
   ...
}
```

and a `log4j2-test.xml` file:

```xml
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <List name="List" />
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
      <AppenderRef ref="List" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

If you run the test classes in parallel, there is a [recent thread](https://lists.apache.org/thread/3n9xqc132pm49w3m67zm6wnjfw6yphkq) on the `log4j-user` mailing list.

**Edit:** If you use JUnit 4, you can use the `LoggerContextRule`:

```java
@Rule
public final LoggerContextRule rule = new LoggerContextRule();

@Test
public void testHeaderFooterValidationWithHeaderFooterInfoDisabled() {
    final ListAppender appender = rule.getAppender("List");

    ...
    // Snapshot of messages
    final List<LogEvent> events = appender.getEvents();
    assertEquals(1, events.size());
    assertEquals("Some Message", events.get(0).getMessage().getFormattedMessage());
    appender.clear();
}
```

Comment: hey, Thanks, I cant use Junit 5, because its legacy code, is there any way we can still use log4j 2.x with the Junit 4 and try to fix the original issues?

Comment: There is also a JUnit 4 version of the extension mentioned above: [`LoggerContextRule`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-core/src/test/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/junit/LoggerContextRule.java).

Comment: Hey, Thanks, I see issue here at `verify(appender, times(1)).doAppend(logCaptor.capture());`, but I don't see how can we fix it ?

Comment: The above solution not working for me, getting `java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender)]`

Comment: @JeffCook: I added an example for JUnit 4. As the JUnit 5 example, this requires `log4j-core` with a `tests` classifier.

Comment: Both Named and LoggerContextSource come from `log4j-core` `test-jar`. If you use Maven, attach it as follows: `<type>test-jar</type>`