# Unit test logs scala/log4j2

Tags: scala, log4j, log4j2

[**Scala**] I have a class someClass with a function A in which I use log4j2 for logging.

```
class someClass {

def A ={
//smt
logger.warn("oups")
}

}
```

In my unit tests someClassTest, I want to collect what A logs and assert the message content.

```
class someClassTest {

it("should log warning") {
//trigger A()
//collect logs
val logs //contain logs
assert(logs(0).contains("oups"))

}

}
```

Theatrically, I should create a custom Appender (extending the AbstractAppender) and collect the logs in a list for example, but I cannot do that, or more like idk how to do that.
Is there other ways to **assert the logs** ? or how to create that custom Appender?

Thank yall

Comment: What is the need to unit test your logs? You don't have test it as it is an external component to your application. At least if you write a wrapper class for you log, you can test your wrapper class.

Comment: in my case the log message is generated depending on conditions and not a simple string, so i want to check if the message is as it should be

Comment: You can mock your logger method and call `verify` to check wether your log method is called or not?

Comment: i spy it instead but i get ```Wanted but not invoked``` even though it normally is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender) removed in Test cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72556197/logger-getrootlogger-addappenderappender-removed-in-test-cases)